# Why Complex Number Derivative Need To Be Same in all Direction?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have recently started complex analysis course , one thing that I do not understand why a complex number derivative need to be same in all direction. Why is such a restriction ? Sorry if this question is too simple to ask here , I just started complex analysis and could not find this answer anywhere where I could find.

If my method of asking the question , please tell so in comments. I would be more than happy to correct them.

Comment: The limit in the definition of the derivative of a real-valued function must also be the same in all directions in order to exist. But on the real line there are only two directions: you can approach $0$ from the left (values inferior to $0$) or from the right (values superior to $0$). In the complex plane, you have an infinity of possible paths to approach $0$.

Comment: Suppose that the limit weren't the same in all directions.  What then would you propose the derivative at that point be equal to?

Comment: @JMoravitz I would say it would depend on the direction. Like it did in multivariable function.

Comment: @Guest You are right in that sense , but why do we have then directional derivatives in case of multivariable function.

Comment: At least part of the reason is that the result of the restriction is a beautiful theory with many fantastic results in it. You can't see that now, if you're just starting, but when you get into it a little more I think you'll be astounded by the wonderful results that come out of this definition.

Comment: You mean conformal mapping , and laplace. right ?

Comment: I mean things like "differentiable implies analytic", and residue theory for integrals, and theory of doubly periodic functions, and, and, and....

Comment: Go for it. Define the "directional derivative" of a complex function as being the limit of the difference quotient along a certain direction, and see what kinds of theorems you can prove about such objects. Remember, when you study mathematics, you're not studying some god-given set of definitions and theorems, you're studying the specific strategies and ideas that human beings happen to have come up with thus far. Nobody said they were the *best* definitions, much less the only possible definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Because there are not really different directions. Whether we walk in "direction" of positive reals or negative imaginaries or whatever, this is all just in the direction of complex numbers. Allowing differences here would be like allowing different limits $\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$ and $\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$ in the real case.

Comment: So why were they different in multivariable calculus. Sorry but I am not really getting the point?

Comment: Because a complex number, despite our convention of writing it in real and complex parts, is not actually two variables but just one, so the "multivariable" case is not applicable.

Comment: So you mean our definition of derivation of complex number requires that no matter in what direction delta(z) points the resultant function would be same . Like no matter x tends zero from left or right it should be equal for limit to exist in single variable function .. am i right /